# debugging chrome remotely - doesn't open websocket

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

Im running chrome headless through chromedriver and selenium via python.
I've run into the following issue both on Mac and Linux.

Im starting chrome as follows:

```py
        if self.headless:
            options.headless = True
            options.add_argument("--headless")

        if self.debug_port:
            logging.info(f"Setting up remote debugging on port {self.debug_port}")
            options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-port={self.debug_port}")
            options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0")
```

If I connect to `http://localhost:9222` from another headed instance of chrome I can see the list of sessions and connect to it seamlessly. At which point i have a window opened up with a screencast of the remote session and the dev console.

Here's that successful example: [image: chrome devtools debugger connected to localhost]

When I connect to `http://192.168.1.194:9222` I get the list of sessions just fine and upon selecting one the dev console opens but it doesn't start the websocket connection to `ws://192.168.1.194` so the screencast and remote debugging capabilities are not available.

Here's that failed example:[image: chrome devtools debugger connected to 192.168.1.194]

I've [captured har files and uploaded them here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d5u9huobhc59htz/AABEM4dI2gXxHJTyL-tHPJg_a?dl=0) if you want to take a look

Comment: https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@3a97857a62ee2a8b3f6561ccd98b9e0436604cbe/inspector.html?ws=localhost:5556/devtools/page/359CF10A6CD6D71E2988625D7C8F8CCD&remoteFrontend=true

Comment: it looks something like this not as ws://localhost , just click inspectable element it shows the devtool automatically

Comment: @PDHide I'm not following what you're saying. everything works fine for me on localhost. it's my local ip address that's hitting an issue.

Comment: Upon further digging I found an error in the console of the main window.

"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@31b458a18f133db9203eb5a5dd6552de0716dda3/inspector.html?ws=192.168.1.194:9222/devtools/page/B55C2067801B09F3D8FB599720E0219F&remoteFrontend=true' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://192.168.1.194:9222/devtools/page/B55C2067801B09F3D8FB599720E0219F'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
Ii @ sdk.js:1"

Answer (score 2):

Using the following steps I was able to debug remotely. However the screencast functionality did not work. Ultimately that's what I needed so this is only a 50% solution in my case.

So, as noted above in the comments, what's blocking remote debugging from working is that the chrome debugger links out to `https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/.....` and passes a value of `ws://192.168.1.194` for the websocket parameter. Any browser will inherently block this, based on it being mixed content - i.e: https + ws

What's needed here is to run the chrome dev tools frontend on a http server
and direct your chrome instance to that server instead of the appspot instance.

## Solution Steps

#### 1 Install depot_tools (pre-requisite for building)

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up

#### 2 Checkout the devtools-frontend repo

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/docs/workflows.md#checking-out-source

#### 3 Build chrome devtools frontend

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/docs/workflows.md#build

#### 4 Start the devtools-frontend http server

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/docs/workflows.md#running-in-hosted-mode

#### 5 Run 2 instances of chrome and use one to debug the other

5.1 Start first instance of chrome headless

...with remote debugging enabled. See the python way in the question above or do it from the command line with the same arguments

5.2 Start a second instance of chrome

...using a different user data dir `--user-data-dir=<some-path>`

5.3 Navigate to http://192.168.1.194:9222

Use whatever the IP address of the first chrome instance is and the port that you chose.

5.4 Create a link to the local dev server

The 2nd instance of chrome will now be showing you links to debug each of the open tabs of the 1st instance. However the links will still to go `https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/....`. You'll need to copy n paste the link you want and replace the hostname with the hostname of the devtools frontend that you started in step 4

Walla!!

If you figure out how to get the screencast working please comment below!

N.B:
I also tried using the `npm run server` command in the devtools frontend but for some reason that server didn't work at all `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`